# jquery label not chaging on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem where a label is not changing on button click. here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="b">aa</button>
    <label id="sum">0</label>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 1;

    $("#b").on('click', function (event) {
        $("#sum").text = "aa";
    });
});
```

Why?

Comment: If you are trying to add the text present in the button to the label then use this: `$("#sum").text($(this).text());`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 1;

    $("#b").on('click', function (event) {
        $("#sum").text("aa");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be:

```
$("#sum").text("aa");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 1;

    $("#b").on('click', function (event) {
        $("#sum").text("aa");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign value using =  in jQuery.

This is wrong in your code `$("#sum").text = "aa";`

Instead this you have to use `$("#sum").text("aa");` which is right way to assign value using jQuery.